# Logging out from Git Credential Manager for Windows

Tags: git

I have tried to use Git to deploy a project into my client's machine (which I do not have control over). It seemed to have **Git Credential Manager for Windows** (which I'm new with) included in the install. So when I tried to `git push` stuff from that machine, it asked me for my credentials (username and password) in a dialog box, which I inputted. When I tried to `git pull` stuff many times, `git` didn't ask me anymore for my credentials.

My questions are:

1. Were my credentials saved in the machine, permanently?
2. If they were saved, how do I remove them (or log out)?
3. How do I check if my credentials were saved?
4. Is it possible for my credentials to be compromised if the client machine was maliciously accessed by other people (repo access; full account compromise)?

Sorry if this is asking too much, as I said I'm new to GCMfW, I haven't even had it installed in my dev machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not using the Git Credential Manager, but it's older brother (wincred), my answer will be based off my knowledge of the older version and the documentation that can be found on it's project repository : https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

To answer each of your questions in order :

1. Were my credentials saved in the machine, permanently : Yes (although they are tied to the user account not every user on the client's machine)
2. Access the account's password secure storage (searching 'vault' in the configuration panel should bring it up) then search and delete an entries with your username on it
3. See above point
4. Consider your credentials compromised ! You don't control what applications are running on your client's machien and every application running using it's account will be able to read the credentials stored in the account vault (AFAIK).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I won't be accessing the machine any time soon, so I'm compelled to accept this answer. Correct me if I'm wrong with this--apparently GCM only stores HTTPS passwords, so I have changed that.

Comment: @cyanbeam Yes, the current version can only store passwords for repositories accessed via HTTPS.

Comment: Note for newbs like me - on Win 7, here's how to do step 2: Start menu -> type "vault" -> click on "Manage Windows Credentials" -> you should see the entry(ies) for git that you can remove